# How to detect if an app is installed then taking actions

Tags: java, android

Inside my app, I want to detect if an app like VLC is installed.
If it does, and when user clicks button, my app will proceed to play a video but if does not, the app will direct user to App store to download the app.

Is there a way to detect if an particular app is installed or not?

Comment: Try breaking your problem down... 1) How to check an **any app** is installed. Ask **that** as a question. 2) How to play a video (using VLC). 3) How to open the Play Store for any application, and then find out how to load the VLC installation page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
List activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(***REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_INTENT***,
        PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
boolean isIntentSafe = activities.size() > 0;
```

From the [Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html#Verify):

> Although the Android platform guarantees that certain intents will
>   resolve to one of the built-in apps (such as the Phone, Email, or
>   Calendar app), you should always include a verification step before
>   invoking an intent.
>
> To verify there is an activity available that can respond to the
>   intent, call queryIntentActivities() to get a list of activities
>   capable of handling your Intent. If the returned List is not empty,
>   you can safely use the intent.
>
> **Note**: You should perform this check when your activity first starts in
>   case you need to disable the feature that uses the intent before the
>   user attempts to use it. If you know of a specific app that can handle
>   the intent, you can also provide a link for the user to download the
>   app (see how to link to your product on Google Play).

So, you could use that like this:

```
Intent vlcIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
vlcIntent.setPackage("org.videolan.vlc");

PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    List activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(vlcIntent,
            PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    boolean isIntentSafe = activities.size() > 0;

if (isIntentSafe){    
    startActivity(vlcIntent);
} else {
    Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    marketIntent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=org.videolan.vlc"));
    startActivity(marketIntent);
}
```

Also, another link that might be useful(VideoLan Wiki):

[Android Video Player Intents](https://wiki.videolan.org/Android_Player_Intents/)
It says:

> For a simple media playback:
>
> ```
>  int vlcRequestCode = 42;  Uri uri =
> Uri.parse("file:///storage/emulated/0/Movies/KUNG FURY Official
> Movie.mp4");  Intent vlcIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
> vlcIntent.setPackage("org.videolan.vlc"); 
> vlcIntent.setDataAndTypeAndNormalize(uri, "video/*"); 
> vlcIntent.putExtra("title", "Kung Fury"); 
> vlcIntent.putExtra("from_start", false); 
> vlcIntent.putExtra("position", 90000l); 
> vlcIntent.putExtra("subtitles_location",
> "/sdcard/Movies/Fifty-Fifty.srt");  startActivityForResult(vlcIntent,
> vlcRequestCode);
> ```
>
> If you specifically want to start VideoPlayerActivity, you can set
>
> ```
>  vlcIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("org.videolan.vlc",
>  "org.videolan.vlc.gui.video.VideoPlayerActivity"));
> ```

You could also put the code into a boolean code block and pass in your intent, that way you could reuse the code. Like this:

```
private boolean checkIntent(Intent intent) {
    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    List activities =     packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,
        PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        boolean isIntentSafe = activities.size() > 0;

        return isIntentSafe;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check to see if the package for VLC is installed. If it is not installed then open the play store showing the vlc install page.

This is the source:

```
String appPackageName = "org.videolan.vlc";
try {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)));
}
```

The source below will check to see if there is anything that can play video and if not, then it will prompt the user to install VLC. This is a more complete example that might help other users. It checks to see if anything locally installed can play the file and then if not, checks for vlc, and if VLC is not installed, then it will take the user to the Play Store.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.fromFile(file));
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
String extension = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(Uri.fromFile(file).toString());
String mimetype = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), mimetype);

PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfoList = manager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
if (resolveInfoList.size() > 0) {
    context.startActivity(intent);
} else {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((AppCompatActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager();
    ClassChatRecyclerAdapter.InstallVlcDialogFragment.newInstance(extension).show(fragmentManager, "INSTALL_VLC");
}
```

This is the dialog that will check for VLC and if it doesn't find it, then it will take the user to the play store to install it. You can take use the try/catch part of the source below to specifically solve your problem.

```
public static class InstallVlcDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public static ClassChatRecyclerAdapter.InstallVlcDialogFragment newInstance(String mediaType) {
        ClassChatRecyclerAdapter.InstallVlcDialogFragment frag = new ClassChatRecyclerAdapter.InstallVlcDialogFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("mediaType", mediaType);
        frag.setArguments(args);
        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String mediaType = getArguments().getString("mediaType");

        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.AppDialogTheme)
                .setTitle("Unable to find video player for " +mediaType + " files.")
                .setMessage("Install VLC Player to play file?")
                .setPositiveButton("OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                String appPackageName = "org.videolan.vlc";
                                try {
                                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
                                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)));
                                }
                                dismiss();
                            }
                        }
                )
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                dismiss();
                            }
                        }
                )
                .create();
    }
}
```

Comment: This method depends on your app files ? Uri.fromFile what is this? And this method is very big

Comment: Please read before you ask questions.

Comment: yes I have read it thanks for your help